# Multiple layout within one activity android

Tags: android, xml, android-activity, layout, layout-inflater

In my activity `IndividualActivity`  i have set the contextview of `individual.xml` now i also want to add another `sub_individual.xml` in the activity *without removing, replacing or hiding* the `individual.xml` so that they remain together.

```
public class IndividualActivity  extends Activity {
       @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.individual);            
        ...
     }
  }
```

**individual.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".IndividualActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/default_wall" >
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listx"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="380dp"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"/>
     ...
```

**sub_individual.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:background="#323331"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="5dip"
    android:text="custom title bar" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bk_btn"
        android:layout_width="35dip"
        android:layout_height="35dip"
        android:background="#DDD" />
    ...
```

Comment: Whilst I agree with everyone saying use fragments (they're much better in long term), you can also use <include /> to do what you're trying to do. See here for details: http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This functionality is supported by using Fragments. See http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: You beat me to it, sir. +1. @SlimShady Fragments are well-documented. (:

Comment: @LittleChild i went through it and it didnt beat me i.e i didnt get it, can you show an example

Comment: @SlimShady Oh no, that "beat me" was for Mr. GreyBeardedPirate :D I was going to post an answer on `Fragments`, too. Look into how to add new fragments using a `FragmentTransaction`. It's fairly straightforward

Comment: Ya so post it Man!  watchya waitin for @LittleChild ?

Comment: There's a pretty good example at http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

If that doesn't do it for you, try looking for "Android Fragment Example" in your favorite search engine, or pick up a book on basic Android development. This is an extremely well-documented framework feature, not a secret.

Comment: @SlimShady mah man ya gotta feel me, yo. You can't just haz teh code. You gotta put in some effort and hit some keys, cook some code. Ya know what I'm sayin' ?

Comment: ayo Homie I fel ya and fried some fragments http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFragments/article.html though helped me

Answer (score 1):

You can use this from xml
Use "include"  tag in your first xml and add second xml in this tag.